# How to handle different input types bound to same ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modernizr

In a page, I have a section for date-range selection. A large portion of our user base is IE 10/11, which does not support input type="date". I'm using Modernizr to show/hide the date input based on the support, and when not, provide an input of type="text", both bound to the same ng-model. Typing into the text spams the console with errors, as the text and date are incompatible. Is there a way to fix this console spam? Using a third-party library is not an option.

```
<div class="col-md-3" data-ng-show="searchBillCreatedDate == 'custom'">
    <label>From</label>
    <input data-ng-model="searchFromDate" type="date" class="form-control" data-ng-show="browser.supportsDateInput">
    <input data-ng-model="searchFromDate" type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-show="!browser.supportsDateInput" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
</div>
```

Comment: "Using a third-party library is not an option"  What?  But you're using angular...?  Angular UI Bootstrap has a datepicker you can use.

Comment: I don't make the rules. Angular UI Bootstrap has been disallowed from the technology stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ng-show to ng-if like this:

```
<input data-ng-model="searchFromDate" type="date" class="form-control" data-ng-if="browser.supportsDateInput">
<input data-ng-model="searchFromDate" type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-if="!browser.supportsDateInput" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

You're getting the error because it's binding to the the first input's model, which is a date input.  ng-show just uses CSS to hide the element but it still exists in the DOM.  ng-if, however, completely removes it from the DOM, leaving you with one ng-model="searchFromDate"

Comment: I didn't realize ng-if removed it from the DOM, I'll give this a whirl. Thanks!

edit: Worked wondrously!